# TurtleBot navigation stack algorithms

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any design doc or research papers that the current turtlebot navigation stack implements?
I would like to learn the algorithms and the top-level design in more depth.
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255829/turtlebot-navigation-stack-algorithms/) by [kangnamtofu](https://answers.ros.org/users/29441/kangnamtofu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2017-02-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The turtlebot uses the ROS [navigation stack](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation), and that wiki page has a great deal of documentation, tutorials, examples and even a few papers about how it works.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kangnamtofu](https://answers.ros.org/users/29441/kangnamtofu/) on 2017-02-28**:
Awesome. Thank you!